# Linq query: how do I default a null value

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a linq query originating from an entity Framework model. I'm having problems with nulls which won't materialize and I can't seem to find a solution for.

Here's partial code showing the Select:

```
.Select(x => new
{
    x.PageConfig.RouteName,
    x.RouteValues,
    x.PageConfig.PhysicalFile,
    MetaLastModified = x.PageMeta.LastModified,
    ImageLastModified = x.FeaturedImage.LastModified,
    SitemapFrequency = x.PageConfig.Sitemap.Frequency,
    SitemapPriority = x.PageConfig.PageType.Priority
})
```

The issue I'm having is that x.**FeaturedImage** can be a null entry, so `LastModified` can't be materialized and is throwing up the problem.

I've tried a few things, including this: `x.FeaturedImage?.LastModified ?? DateTime.MinValue`, but can't get it to work.

How do I get round this?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: by "not work", I mean that - aside from the original code (which compiles but throws a runtime error) - I've not been able to work out a "nullable" syntax that will actually compile. Sorry, if this seems like a rather basic problem, but it ain't my forte.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing exactly. What do you mean by "originating from an entity Framework model"? The query as-is should work as a LINQ to entities query.

Comment: @GertArnold the query works fine but it's the data that's causing me issues. Not every row has a "featured image", and consequently it can be null. Thus I'm getting "LastModified" can't be materialized at runtime. I just need to catch the null and default it to a valid DateTime.

Comment: Something like `ImageLastModified = x.FeaturedImage != null ? x.FeaturedImage.LastModified : DateTime.Now`

Comment: I'm trying to get clear in what type of query this `Where` runs, because that makes a huge difference. Is it against a `DbSet` from EF? Besides that, it would help to give exact exception messages instead of a summary. Also, the EF version is important. Please edit your question and add the relevant info and tag.

Comment: What @GertArnold said. It would help to better understand if we had the full query and the exception. Maybe you are missing an Include() or even ThenInclude()?